# How should I write "(the) number of unique items { is / are } few"?

Tags: articles, countability

Which sentence is correct and why?

> If the number of unique items is few
>
> If number of unique items are few

Note:

- Should I use ***the***?
- Should I use ***number*** or ***numbers***?
- should I use ***is*** or ***are***?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Should I use the?

Yes, you should use the article in front of *number*.

- Should I use number or numbers?

If it is *one* set of items you are talking about, it is *one* number of items, so you use the singular.

- should I use is or are?

Number is singular, so you use the verb in the singular.

**However**, there is another point: the use of *few*. **Few** means that there is a small number of items, but the *number* is not *few*, its is *small*.
So you could say the following:

> If there are (only) a few unique items...

**or**

> If the number of unique items is small...

Mixing them up is comparable to "that item costs expensive", which is a mix of "it is expensive"  and "it costs a lot".